# Set up seaborn/matplotlib to always use edgecolor='k' parameter

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn

I am constructing a lot of bar plots which are all in the same style, for example

```
import seaborn as sns                                                       
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt                                             

sns.set_style('darkgrid')
# some more configuration options that work as expected here
sns.barplot([1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], edgecolor='k')
```

which gives

[image]

Is there a way to configure my plotting environment to always use `edgecolor='k'` such that I don't have to pass the parameter every time?

**I tried**

```
sns.set_style(rc={'patch.force_edgecolor':True})
```

but it has no effect. If I don't explicitly use `edgecolor='k'` when plotting then the bars don't have an edge.

I also noticed that there is

```
plt.rc('edgecolor', ???)
```

but I cannot figure out what to pass for `???` (it has to be a keyword argument).

---

edit:

Using

```
sns.set_style(rc={'patch.force_edgecolor':True})
```

does not work, but using

```
sns.set_style(rc={'patch.force_edgecolor':True,
                   'patch.edgecolor': 'black'})
```

works as expected. I don't understand why `'patch.edgecolor': 'black'` is necessary here since this seems to be the default setting.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `patch`, as in:

```
plt.rcParams['patch.edgecolor'] = 'black'
```

You can also do:

```
plt.rc('patch', edgecolor='black')
```

Answer (score 1):

I can now explain what went wrong with `sns.set_style`.

`sns.set_style('darkgrid')` sets `'patch.edgecolor'` to `'w'`, that's why it has to be manually set to `'black'` again.